# Why is $z = \frac{a}{b}$ a singularity of $ \frac{1}{z|az-b|^2} $?

Tags: complex-numbers

Could someone explain why $z = \frac{a}{b}$ is a singularity of $ \frac{1}{z|az-b|^2} $?

Am I mistaken something?

Comment: Do you mean $z=\frac{b}a$ is a singularity? @Ignite

Comment: Did you mean $z=b/a$? If so, because the expression is not defined when the denominator is 0.

Comment: No, it is $\frac{a}{b}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $a\neq0,\, b \neq0$. We have
$$
a z -b=0 \Leftrightarrow z=\frac{b}{a},
$$ then $\displaystyle z=\frac{a}{b}$ is *not* a singularity of the denominator unless
$$
a \cdot\frac{a}{b} -b=0 \Leftrightarrow a^2=b^2.
$$

Comment: The last line makes a lot of sense $-$ "unless".
At a first glance $\frac{a}{b}$ doesn't seem to be the zero of $z|az-b|^2$, but after take a careful look, it is.